# prob. 3, project Euler

Tags: python

Problem 3 on Project Euler is:

The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

I've written a program that works:

```
n =600851475143
i = 2
while i * i < n: #square root law
    while n % i == 0: #isolates factors
        n = n/i 
i = i + 1
print (n)
```

However, when I tried to answer it a different way and came up with this code:

```
def primes(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n**.5)):
        while n % i == 0:
            n = n / i
     print (n)
 primes(600851475143)
```

and my console is returning the value 1.0. So, my main questions are: why in the world is 1.0 being returned :(, and what is so different between the initial while loop in the first code and the for loop in the faulty code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: your working code kinda works by chance. Try input like 75, and it will fail. As far as the differences in the code go:

The condition of your while loop `i * i < n` is evaluated after each iteration where both `i` AND `n` change inside the loop body. Here, when you reach the target prime, let's assume `5`, both `i` and `n` are 5 and the loop stops because `25` >= `5`

You for-loop iterates more times since the range is set only once in the beginning, so the loop will always iterate to the upper limit specified in your range. Here, in our outlined case: n = n/5 will just be executed until `n` is `1`

Comment: thanks, this makes so much sense!! as for how my "working code" fails with 75, is it because it doesn't work whenever a squared number comes up?